# Best way to adjust parts of sculpt?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, sculpting

is there a way to edit a specific part of the object in sculpt mode? (rotate, scale)

I have sculpted my mouth too small and would like to scale it up. So my method right now would be to go to edit mode and select the part I want to scale with c and then scale it. However the C select is not symmetrical and also not smooth but just hard.

Is there a better way to adjust parts of a sculpt? For example putting a mask on the are in sculpt mode and then scaling it up somehow?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try the Inflate brush. If it doesn`t work, you can try the pull brush.

Comment: Yes, it's better to avoid messing with Edit mode when sculpting is already done, move those in sculpting. There are Grab brush (doesn't change topology with Dyntopo), SnakeHook (this one does change), Nudge, Thumb (default ones).